# Optimal ways to traverse through YAML in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml

I have a YAML file which I need to work with every now and then:

```
environments_definition:
    environment:
        default:
          stack_profile: 'snapshot_volume_mounted'
          stack_params:
            private_net_id :
                value: "inner-net"
                to_id: "network"
          action:
            someaction: "do_that_Action"
```

I traverse through this YAML file, and do any of the below

1. store stack_profile is one function, store `stack_params` in another function( in form of dictionary).
2. if I find action in `stack_params`, I grab "do_that_Action" and on the basis of that do something
3. I also update some of the values in this YAML. E.g.

   ```
   env_default_params = self.orch_params["environments_definition"]["environment"]['default']
   ```

or

```
    if 'action' in env_params:
            action_params = env_params['action']
            for key in action_params.keys():
                if type(action_params[key]) is dict:
                    if (action_params[key]['action'] == 'do_that_Action'):
                        do_that_Action
                    else:
                        print("No action")
```

These are a few examples. I wanted to know if there is a cleaner way of traversing through the YAML. Every time I have to find something in YAML, I have to use

```
env_default_params = self.orch_params["something"]["something"].
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: What do you consider cleaner? That the YAML file remembers what you accessed last time and remembers that? That you have to use no, or less, square brackets and quotes? I'd expect you to be way more worried about the ugliness of the way you walk over the keys and find actions to execute.

Comment: I totally agree and I don't like to use quotes every time I have to traverse through the yaml. I would like to know a non-ugly way to work with this.